which static analysis tool can give a report on code issues even if there is syntax errors?
i tried to use pylint and some other linters, but they get stuck parsing when they come across syntax error. I need to find a tool or library that find code smells related issues like pylint even with syntax errors.
I tried to get every issues related to a code using linters but they can't parse the code when there is syntax errors and only show that syntax error as a message

Have you tried disable=syntax-error?

yes I have tried disable=syntax-error but it does not give other issues even if there is. It fails to parse even after disabling syntax error

What kind of code are you trying to rate and why is there so much syntax error in it ?
